# Tool to get "Timeline" of browser events (including browser events like script evaluation, not just network events) in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, testing, browser

Simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere on SO or otherwise. In webkit's (Chrome/Safari) Developer Tools I can use the "Timeline" functionality to get an exactly look at precisely what is going on inside the browser while it loads a page (when it's evaluating script, when it's painting the screen, when it's downloading resources, etc.). I can also get the same information through Chrome's "Page Speed" extension.

Is there anything like this for Firefox?

I'm experiencing an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731330/recaptcha-script-tag-injection-failing-sporadically) where basically a script is not executing properly but there are no error messages in the console to give me any hit as to what is wrong. I want to try to get a more "in-depth" look at exactly what is happening and when so that I might find a clue as to what is going awry.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network) has a timeline feature.

Comment: I'm not just looking for network events though, I'm looking for detailed information on when js is actually evaluated as well.